# Can Brownian motion explain why white smoke moves around in the air?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry, molecules, brownian-motion

Can **Brownian motion** explain why **white smoke (fume) generated by chemical reactions** moves around in the air?

Answer (score 2):

Brownian motion would cause a slow spread. “Moving around” probably indicates convection.  Your chemical reaction may be exothermic.

Comment: I learned that the spread of cigarette smoke is an example of the Brownian movement. Is the spread of smoke in the text different from cigarette smoke?

Comment: Brownian motion is movement of atoms caused by another invisible atoms in a zig Zag way . So I think yes . However density of fumes also play a role , it is warm and less dense air that rises up .I think convention is also at play .